# Car rentals in USA for drivers under age 25

Tags: usa, car-rentals, age-limits

Most companies in the US have a heavy surcharge on drivers under the age of 25. What is worse is that it doesn't matter if you are 21 or 24.9 when you rent. What can be done by under 25 drivers to rent cars cheaply?

Comment: I read your title as "Car rentals in the USA for fewer than 25 drivers."  I hope you don't mind that I edited it :)

Answer (score 4):

A good idea to escape the young  renters' surcharge is to do your research well. The car rental business is very competitive and almost all agencies have discounts running all throughout the year, if one were to look closer. The most famous offer being the weekend discount. 
In fact, Hertz has a [no young renters' surcharge offer](http://www.hertz.com.au/rentacar/a-14273969/no-young-renter-surcharge-special-offer) running currently.

Another feasible option is to sign up on [popular sites](http://blog.webcarhire.com/category/deals-of-the-week/) which list down rental discounts and offers from various industries.

Comment: I think Hertz has almost always the young surcharge waiver offer running. But be careful, if you compare its price with an adult without any offer, it might still be more expensive.

Comment: Good point!
It's always wise to make a cost-benefit analysis.

Answer (score 3):

When I was in Colorado years ago, we were investigating this, as most companies wouldn't rent to us (being under 25 at the time).

Back then, Hertz was suggested as a company that would rent to us, and potentially without a surcharge.

For example, they had [this special available to waive this surcharge](https://www.hertz.com/rentacar/q-12808263/save-up-to-%2425-a-day-if-you-re-20-24-years-old-special-offer), so it won't cost you any extra to rent, being younger than 25.  That one has now expired, but I also wouldn't be surprised if they and other companies offer these specials on a semi-regular basis - car hire is fairly competitive.  Ringing them up and saying one of the other companies offered it might get you a matched offer from your company of choice - doesn't hurt to try!

Comment: The Hertz special seems to have expired in 2010, unless you're seeing something different from me.

Comment: @waiwai933 - geofenced? 2010 is nowhere on the page for me, US/Canada only, and it says it expires Sep 30?

Comment: It's at the end of the Terms and Conditions: *Offer valid for vehicle pickup through 09-30-10*.

Comment: @waiwai933 well that's just dumb. All other appearances indicate this year. I wonder if they'd still honour it :/  I'll update my answer.  Good spotting!

Comment: I updated the link to the current promotion.  Valid through 8/31/13

Answer (score 2):

My experience was that the smaller, non-national places had more reasonable under-25 rates than the majors. Try kayak.com and see if the "rent-a-wreck" agencies will quote you a better total price (though of course the cars are typically not in as good condition).