# What is the minimum age to drive a rental car in the US?

Tags: usa, legal, car-rentals, automobiles, age-limits

I recognized that renting a car in the US is allowed at the age of 21 or 25. But are 18 to 21 year olds allowed to drive it if their parents or another 25 year old person signed the contract?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Car rentals in USA for drivers under age 25](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18415/car-rentals-in-usa-for-drivers-under-age-25)

Comment: @Karlson how is this even possibly a duplicate?  The other question (nor it's answers) mentions *nothing* about the 18-20 age range that this question is talking talk.

Answer (score 11):

The age of majority in the United States is 18, and that is the theoretical *legal* age required to enter into a rental contract— but it takes two to agree to a contract. In practice, it may not be possible to find someone willing to offer a rental contract to someone under 21 depending on the

- rental agency
- rental location/market
- size and type of vehicle
- payment method

In the states of New York and Michigan, state law requires agencies to rent to licensed drivers 18 and over, though such drivers will be subject to heavy surcharges (sometimes prohibitive, over $100/day) and restrictions. Otherwise, none of the major agencies will rent to anyone under 21 except for U.S. military personnel or others renting on official government business.

Of the smaller agencies, [Rent-A-Wreck](https://www.rentawreck.com/info.htm) allows 18-year-olds at some locations, [Fox](http://www.foxrentacar.com/customer-support/faqs.aspx) rents to 19-year-olds, and [Ace](http://www.acerentacar.com/faq.aspx?id=7) offers that it may be possible depending on the location, and local agencies may also be willing to offer you a car.

"Additional drivers" are not exempt from minimum age requirements, and these will also vary by all the listed factors. For example, Hertz allows 20-year-olds, but National and Avis require 21, except in certain markets.

Answer (score 6):

Car rental contracts typically specify that the car may be driven *only* by the person(s) listed on the contract.  So the child wouldn't be allowed to drive a car rented by their parent unless they were added to the contract, in which case the rental company's age restrictions might kick in.

Comment: And probably if you try to do so, no insurance will cover any damage.

Answer (score 3):

Zipcar is one possible (if very limited) option:

> Some of Zipcar’s university partners offer the service to students, faculty, and staff aged 18 years and older. For participating universities, members must have a drivers license for at least two years and can have no violations on their records. ([Source](http://org.elon.edu/sustainability/documents/Zipcar%20FAQs.pdf))